# C# JSON deserialization with polymorphism - workaround for putting discriminator at the start of an object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, polymorphism, .net-7.0

I'm using JSON (de-)serialization with polymorphism as it was introduced in .NET 7 by using type discriminators. The big issue is that it forces the discriminator to be the first object in a JSON structure. This somewhat clashes with many JSON specs which regard JSON objects as unsorted key-value pairs. So, I'm wondering if there is any possible workaround when building an ASP.NETCore Web API, e.g. through some middleware-preprocessor etc. to re-order incoming request objects before they are handed over to deserialization?

> **Note**
>
> The type discriminator must be placed at the start of the JSON object, grouped together with other metadata properties like $id and $ref.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#polymorphic-type-discriminators

Comment: The better option would be writing custom serializer supporting unordered type info.